# Coffeescript - referencing class methods in onclick

Tags: coffeescript

I'm just wondering how I can get this to work?

Trying to reference a method at an onclick

```
class C

  @f: () ->
    alert 'works'
    null

  constructor: () ->
    console.log @f # why is this undefined?
    document.onclick = @f

new C()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because `@f` compiles to `this.f` and `this` is constructor function itself.

To access class method `f` you have to write `C.f`:

```
class C

    @f: () ->
        alert 'works'
        null

    constructor: () ->
        console.log C.f
        document.onclick = C.f
```

Comment: You could also use `@constructor.f` if you don't want to drag an explicit class name around.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wanted to bind an instance method and not a class method

```
class C
    #this defines a class method
    @f: () ->
        alert 'works'
        null

    #this is an instance method
    f: () ->
        alert 'works'
        null

    constructor: () ->
        console.log @f # why is this undefined?
        document.onclick = @f

 new C()
```